# Transaction Scope in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-2.0

I use Grails Hibernate transactions to do the following in a Controller Action:

```
user.save(flush:true)

User.withTransaction {
  user.name = "newName"
  user.save(flush: true)
}
```

What does Hibernate/Grails do in this case? When I flush the hibernate session on the first flush does the withTransaction creates a new session or will it attach the two saves in one session?

Comment: is this part of a Controller or a Service?

Comment: @drorb it is part of a Controller action

Answer (score 4):

If it's in a controller action, then there will be a Hibernate session open the whole time since the OpenSessionInView interceptor starts that for you at the beginning of the request. The `withTransaction` call uses the current thread-local session.

Note that transaction will flush the session, so there's no need to do it explicitly. Also note that you really shouldn't be polluting controller code with transactions and other persistence (or business) logic - this code should be in a transactional service method.

Comment: Does it change anything if I do not use withTransaction here?

Comment: Only that the 2nd save won't be done in a transaction. In 2.3 the generated controllers have an `@Transactional` annotation, but without that (and in earlier versions of Grails) there's no active transaction in controllers by default. That's why services are the best place for database updates.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith just to clarify this ... then grails services are like transactional annotated by default?

Comment: Yes, but it's the same as using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. You want to use the newer `grails.transaction.Transactional` annotation which has the same features and avoids the problem where calling another annotated method internally ignores the annotation attributes.